# Firebase Unity3D Android build with IL2CPP: libApp.so, error: Cannot load library

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

I checked out the messaging sample app (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/messaging/testapp), and try to build for Android platform. With the scripting backend option is Mono2x, everything is working ok on device, but with option IL2CPP, the Android logcat shows following errors on Firebase initialize method:

```
11-14 10:31:17.233: E/Unity(5088): Couldn't open /data/app-lib/com.firebase.testfcm-1/libApp.so, error: Cannot load library:
11-14 10:31:17.233: E/Unity(5088): System.Threading.Tasks.<Post>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Object)
11-14 10:31:17.233: E/Unity(5088): [ line 125]
11-14 10:31:17.233: E/Unity(5088): (Filename:  Line: 125)
11-14 10:31:17.253: I/Unity(5088): DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'App': The specified module could not be found.
11-14 10:31:17.253: I/Unity(5088):   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, Firebase.ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-14 10:31:17.253: I/Unity(5088):   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-14 10:31:17.253: I/Unity(5088):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Transform`1[TKey,TValue,TRet].EndInvoke (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-14 10:31:17.253: I/Unity(5088):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler+<
```

Has anyone have same problems?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.

unpack the apk, found libApp.so not in the apk file.

I use unity to export gradle project.

finally, I found exported gradle project not include the aars in the lib folder.
I add to include aar in the build.gradle and this problem sovled.